# Google Dataflow - Invalid Regional Endpoint - Impossible set region on template from nodejs client

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline stored as a template. I'm using the node.js client to run this pipeline from a cloud function. Everything works fine, but when I need to run this template from different regions I get errors.

According to the documentation, I can set it through the location parameter in the payload

```
{
  projectId: 123,
  resource: {
    location: "europe-west1",
    jobName: `xxx`,
    gcsPath: 'gs://xxx'
  }
}
```

That gives me the following error:

```
The workflow could not be created, since it was sent to an invalid regional endpoint (europe-west1). 
Please resubmit to a valid Cloud Dataflow regional endpoint.
```

I get the same error if I move the location parameter out of resource node, such as:

```
{
  projectId: 123,
  location: "europe-west1",
  resource: {
    jobName: `xxx`,
    gcsPath: 'gs://xxx'
  }
}
```

If I set the zone in the environment and remove the location such as:

```
{
  projectId: 123,
  resource: {
    jobName: `xxx`,
    gcsPath: 'gs://xxx',
    environment: {
        zone: "europe-west1-b"
    }
   }
}
```

I do not get any errors anymore, but dataflow UI tells me the job is running in `us-east1`

How can I run this template and providind the region / zone I

Comment: Does it work if you specify `us-central1` using `location` too? Are you using a [deprecated SDK](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints#using_regional_endpoints) or [Shuffle service](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints#common_scenarios) that do not support all regional endpoints?

Comment: Yes it does if I specify us-central1. I'm using the latest googleapis version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1034#issuecomment-372580070), there are actually two endpoints:

- `dataflow.projects.locations.templates.launch` ([API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/dataflow/v1b3/dataflow.projects.locations.templates.launch))
- `dataflow.projects.templates.launch` ([API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/dataflow/v1b3/dataflow.projects.templates.launch))

For Dataflow regional endpoints to work, the first one must be used (`dataflow.projects.locations.templates.launch`). This way, the `location` parameter in the request will be accepted. Code snippet:

```
var dataflow = google.dataflow({
    version: "v1b3",
    auth: authClient
});

var opts = {
    projectId: project,
    location: "europe-west1",
    gcsPath: "gs://path/to/template",
    resource: {
        parameters: launchParams,
        environment: env
    }
};
dataflow.projects.locations.templates.launch(opts, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    res.send(result.data);
});
```

Comment: thank you, this fixed it for me too. However from an api point of view it makes absolutely no sense to have such a confusing and error prone structure... wtf

Answer (score 1):

I have been testing this though both the [API explorer](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.templates/launch) and the [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow/createjob) using [Google-provided templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates). Using the `wordcount` example I get the same generic error than you do with the API explorer, which is the same if the `location` name is incorrect. However, the Console provides more information:

> Templated Dataflow jobs using Java or Python SDK version prior to 2.0
>   are not supported outside of the us-central1 Dataflow Regional
>   Endpoint. The provided template uses Google Cloud Dataflow SDK for
>   Java 1.9.1.

Which is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints#using_regional_endpoints) as I previously commented. Running it confirms it's using a deprecated SDK version. I would recommend doing the same process to see if this is actually your case, too.

Choosing a different template, in my case the `GCS Text to BigQuery` option from the Console's drop-down menu (which uses `Apache Beam SDK for Java 2.2.0`) with `location` set to `europe-west1` works fine for me (and the job actually runs in that region).

**TL;DR**: your request is correct in your first example but you'll need to update the template to a newer SDK if you want to use regional endpoints.

Comment: The template was created using Java SDK 2.3.0

Comment: Can you try executing it from the UI to see if you get a more detailed error message?

Comment: If I run it through the ui (api explorer) i get a 200 response code but the job doesn’t get launched. I’ll try it again later to check I did it correctly

Comment: That's interesting. Could be specific to the node.js client then. I meant the console though, which gives the most detailed message: https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow/createjob

Comment: I’ll try that and I’ll let you know. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I also get the same error with the client library. I checked and saw that you already opened an [issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1034) in their tracker

Comment: Yes I created a github issue but it didn't get much traction so far. I just saw you added a comment on it. Thanks.

Comment: mahmoudhanafy found the [solution to the issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1034#issuecomment-372580070): we should use the `dataflow.projects.locations.templates.launch` endpoint instead of `dataflow.projects.templates.launch`