# Google Dataflow - Invalid Regional Endpoint - Impossible set region on template from Go client

Tags: go, google-cloud-dataflow

```golang
import (
    dataflow "cloud.google.com/go/dataflow/apiv1beta3"
    "cloud.google.com/go/functions/metadata"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    dataflowpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/dataflow/v1beta3"
    "log"
    "os"
)

...

func KickDataflow(ctx context.Context, start, end string) error {
    client, err := dataflow.NewTemplatesClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer client.Close()

    req := &dataflowpb.CreateJobFromTemplateRequest{
        ProjectId: "xxx",
        JobName:   fmt.Sprintf("transform-orders_%s", start),
        Template: &dataflowpb.CreateJobFromTemplateRequest_GcsPath{
            GcsPath: gcsPath,
        },
        Parameters: map[string]string{
            "input": fmt.Sprintf("gs://xxx/order_updates/dt=%s/orders_%s_%s.jsonl", start, start, end),
        },
        Environment: &dataflowpb.RuntimeEnvironment{
            NumWorkers:          int32(1),
            MaxWorkers:          int32(3),
            WorkerZone:          "asia-northeast1-b",
            TempLocation:        tempLocation,
            ServiceAccountEmail: os.Getenv("SERVICE_ACCOUNT"),
        },
        Location: "asia-northeast1",
    }
    _, err = client.CreateJobFromTemplate(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

It returns the error.

> error in kicking dataflow job: rpc error: code = FailedPrecondition desc = (9abc46254fa5372d): The workflow could not be created, since it was sent to an invalid regional endpoint (asia-northeast1). Please resubmit to a valid Cloud Dataflow regional endpoint. The list of Cloud Dataflow regional endpoints is at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints.

There seems to be the same issue in Node.js client.
[Google Dataflow - Invalid Regional Endpoint - Impossible set region on template from nodejs client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053048/google-dataflow-invalid-regional-endpoint-impossible-set-region-on-template?rq=1)

How to resolve this issue using Go client?

Comment: Hi Yu, what version SDK are you using?

Comment: Also, what version SDK was the template built with?

Comment: @Cubez Thanks. I'm using cloud.google.com/go/dataflow v0.1.0